# TRIM Function for only rows with yesterday's Date

Tags: excel, vba, trim

I have this TRIM function running but to save time would like to only run it on the previous days rows, column G contains a Date.

Please can someone guide me to achieving this.

```vb
sub TrimText()
Dim lRow As Integer

With Worksheets("Data")
    lRow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lRow
        .Cells(i, "A").Value = Trim(.Cells(i, "A").Value)
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that there will be a date stored in column G, and if that date is yesterday when running - then the `TRIM` code should run on that row:

```
For i = 2 To lRow
    If .Cells(i, "G").Value = Int(Now()) - 1 Then
        .Cells(i, "A").Value = Trim(.Cells(i, "A").Value)
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

If your doing this for the sake of speed/time, adding code to check the date isn't the way to go about it really.

However, assuming the date in column G is DD/MM/YYY (or whatever order your system uses in a `Date` formatted column), this will check the value in column G and skip if the date is yesterday (purely date, no time)

```
Sub TrimText()
Dim lRow As Integer

Dim Yesterday As Date
Dim Test As Date
Yesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Now)
Test = DateSerial(Year(Yesterday), Month(Yesterday), Day(Yesterday))

With Worksheets("Data")
    lRow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lRow
        If .Cells(i, "G").Value = Test Then
            ' date in G is Yesterday
            .Cells(i, "A").Value = Trim(.Cells(i, "A").Value)
        Else
            ' date in G is NOT Yesterday
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Turning off screenupdating will make your original macro run faster since the slowest part of your macro is the Excel UI and not the code.

```
Sub TrimText()
Dim lRow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Worksheets("Data")
    lRow = .Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lRow
        .Cells(i, "A").Value = Trim(.Cells(i, "A").Value)
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```